# Extension method and Regular Method => Error?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I have two methods that are identical.
one is

```
    public void ExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Window w, int amount)
    {
        if (internals.DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
        {
            WindowInteropHelper wi = new WindowInteropHelper(w);
            internals.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(wi.Handle, new internals.MARGINS(amount));
        }
    }
```

and the other is

```
public void ExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this Window w,int amount)
        {
            this.ExtendFrameIntoClientArea(w, amount);
        }
```

One of them is an extension method and the other one is not. This however, results in an error "This call is ambiguous"

How would I work around this?

Comment: Does it compile? Extensions methods must be static...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods should be static.

```
public static class XExtender
{
    public static void A(this X x)
    {
        x.A(x);
    }
}
public class X
{
    public void A(X x)
    {

    }
}
```

Extension methods should have a static class and a static method.

Comment: I believe this is just a typo - won't compile without the static modifier.

Comment: I just wonder: An extension method will never be called if it has the same signature as a method defined in the type: http://bit.ly/91A9Jn (General Guidelines), so whats the point?

Answer (score 1):

According to [C# Version 3.0 Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047%28VS.80%29.aspx), the [search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047%28VS.80%29.aspx#cs3spec_topic3) is:

- instance method in the type definition
- extension method in the current namespace
- extension method in the current namespace’s parents namespaces
- extension method in the other namespaces imported by “using”

So how you declared your methods and where?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is not caused by the extension method.

First, an extension method

```
public static void ExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this Window w, int amount) { }
```

(by the way, you missed the `static` modifier) would be ambiguous with a instance method

```
public void ExtendFrameIntoClientArea(int amount) { }
```

declared in the class `Window` but not with a instance method

```
public void ExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Window w, int amount) { }
```

no matter in what class it is declared. Further - as far as I remember - instance methods take precedence over extension method - so they should never be ambiguous with extension methods. I suggest to have a look at the error message again and verify that you are looking at the right methods.